# Debussy Prelude "le vent dans la plaine" - Practice tricks

Tags: piano, technique

I will soon try to start another prelude by Claude Debussy. So far I played:

- Danseuses de Delphes
- Voiles
- Des pas sur la neige
- La fille aux cheveux de lin
- La cathédrale engloutie

Now I want to start with le vent dans la plaine. My questions:
**how would you practice the "wind-like" movement in the right hand which is supposed to be played in pp?** Especially the weak 4th and 5th fingers. Any recommendations, hints?

Mercie!

Comment: Good music! But, yes, tough technical demands. I'd do _other_ exercises for 4th and 5th, to beef them up... :)

Comment: Incredibly good music! Which exercises would you recommend for 4th and 5th?

Comment: Ages ago, I did lots of Hanon-type exercises, insisting on precision, separation and so on, and it definitely helped my fingers. In some regards, sometimes, what is needed is not only musical subtlety, but the muscular capacity to _be_ subtle., which is often gained by doing some otherwise-not-very-musical exercises. :)

Comment: I agree. I am a fan of Dohnanyi finger exercises. It's a pretty helpful compendium of exercises to develop strength and independence. https://www.amazon.com/Essential-Finger-Exercises-Ernst-Dohnanyi/dp/1480304883

Comment: My instinct would be to use 3 and 4 instead of 4 and 5 (only works if your hand can reach it comfortably though), or to alternate between (3,4) and (4,5) to reduce fatigue from doing exactly the same motion again and again and again.